# URL Fetch within Google App Engine between Python app and Node app running in Managed VM

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps, google-app-engine-python

My team is exploring the possibility of cross-application communication within Google App Engine environment. We have our core Python app running on GAE, and a new NodeJS App running on GAE Managed VM. So far we could only find information on URL fetch service supported in Python, Java, and Go.

Does anyone know if URL fetch service is available in Node running on GAE managed VM?
Or is there other solution my team can use for high-performing cross-application communication within Google's network infrastructure for efficiency and scaling purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The URL Fetch service is not available for NodeJS on app engine. However, for cross-application communication, you can use [Google Cloud Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/). You can use the [Google Cloud Client library for NodeJS](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node) to access the Pub/Sub service from a NodeJS app running on a flexible VM.